# CSS Selectors for multiple decendant types #example> div,p,a{}

Tags: css

## Okay I believe the simple answer is css is flawed in this way, and cannot be done without SAAS or other techniques that do not support browsers like i.e. or Edge *I need them too.*

Since I cannot use SASS/LESS or :matches() what I have done is found a tool that converts SASS to css. this allows me to write css faster. 
Link: https://www.sassmeister.com/

:matches() would work but does not support i.e. and edge,
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/

also SAAS would work like so

```
section, article, aside, nav {
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

## Original Question

I was curious if there is a way to create a list of a descendant of a class, type, or id.

example is class hello

```
.hello a, .hello div, .hello p{ 
    stuff
}
```

if this is how it has to be done it seems like a flaw in css... I was looking more for something like

```
.hello > a,div,p
{
     stuff
} but this doesn't work
```

Something like this, but only if each item is a descendant of a certain id..
may #example
The only way I have gotten it to work is to literally type out #example body, #example div, #example span .... etc. I would assume there is a way to just say

## .example > (make, comma, seperated, list){}

for really long ones like this..

```
 body,  div,  span,  applet,  object,  iframe,
 h1,  h2,  h3,  h4,  h5,  h6,  p,  blockquote,  pre,  hr,
 a,  abbr,  address,  cite,  code,
 del,  dfn,  em,  img,  ins,  kbd,  q,  s,  samp,
 small,  strong,  sub,  sup,  tt,  var,
 b,  u,  i,
 dl,  dt,  dd,  ol,  ul,  li,
 fieldset,  form,  label,  legend,
 table,  caption,  tbody,  tfoot,  thead,  tr,  th,  td,
article,  aside,  canvas,  details,  figcaption,  figure,
footer,  header,  hgroup,  menu,  nav,  section,  summary,
time,  mark,  audio,  video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have seen examples only for single items. If adding id in front of everysingle one is how you do it, then so be it.

Basically I want to know how to do this that pertains to a certain class or id without having to write the id in front of every single one of them.

Comment: look at SASS/LESS

Answer (score 1):

I only did about 15 minutes of digging. But it looks like due to spotty browser support, this feature doesn't really exist in any implementable way.

Here's a CSS Tricks article I found about the '**:matches()**' pseudo class.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/

It links to this caniuse page which will show you that many browsers either don't support it or are deprecating their past vendor-prefixed implementation.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-matches-pseudo

Comment: Thanks for the share on info, it is great, but I have to support edge and ie :( But will keep this in mind for the future. Since this is created and saas has been created, I would assume it is not a standard feature in css, hence why I couldn't find an answer. I will upvote this for now.

Comment: That was my assumption as well. Glad I could help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

To match all descendants of `<something>`,

```
something > *
```

So for `class="example"`:

```
.example > *
```

[Here are all of the relationships and matches](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). You missed the third one on the list, `*`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not meaning all. I am meaning some. But lists can get large from time to time.

Comment: My main question is how do you make a list of elements that are a descendant of something. For example #example > div, a, p, .... {} If I do this it doesn't work. I would assume, and I may be wrong that I should have to write #example > div, #example a, #example p {} If i do have to do this, it seems like a flaw in css.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with CSS only (at the moment). But you can use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS to write rules like this:

```
#example {
    span, div {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

> **demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/mq5w0ex1/3/

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting a feeling this isn't a standard thing with css. I would love to use SASS, but cannot :( I believe I have my answer, which is no.